ChromeDriver Assuming Crash: The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running
I am working on a web scraping bot using Selenium in Python. My setup involves using webdriver.Chrome and I am running into an issue where the ChromeDriver assumes that Chrome has crashed. Here are the details of my setup and the error message:
The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os
import time

class VannilaBotV1(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=webdriver.Chrome):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        options = Options()
        prefs = {
            "translate_whitelists": {"it": "en"},
            "translate": {"enabled": "true"}
        }
        # options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        extension_path = os.path.join("./extensions/hcaptcha_extension.crx")
        options.add_extension(extension_path)
        super(VannilaBotV1, self).__init__(options=options)
        self.set_window_size(1040, 1440)

This is how I am running inside my local machine. It's running so comfortably but it's not running inside my ubuntu vps.
System Information:

Chrome Location: /usr/bin/google-chrome
Chrome Version: Google Chrome 126.0.6478.61
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Ensured that Chrome is installed correctly and is accessible via the specified path.
Checked for any potential issues with the ChromeDriver and Chrome version compatibility.
Ensured that the --no-sandbox argument is included.
Attempted to run without headless mode (still encountered issues).
Despite these steps, the issue persists. I am not sure what is causing ChromeDriver to assume that Chrome has crashed.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

you don't show driver initialization code here.... but check to be sure major versions of chrome and chromedriver match.  Also check without setting any options or adding extensions.  Certain extensions are not compatible with driver and certain options can crash browser.  If you find it works without those, add them back one at a time to see which might be causing an issue.

The same code running smoothly inside my local machine
